# applicationWillEnterForeground present a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a PIN view controller which needs to be presented every time the `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` fires. I have multiple view controllers and when the app enters background the user could be on any of them.

The problem is I don't know how to present the PIN view controller over any view controller that is currently active. Here's how my implementation looks:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ResourceSingleton *resource = [ResourceSingleton sharedSingleton];
    if ([resource checkIfPINIsEnabled])
    {
        PinViewController *pinView = [[PinViewController alloc] initWithMode:kPINViewControllerModeEnter];
        pinView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pinView animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

But the PIN view appears only if I'm at the first view controller (the root one). How to pop it up on any view controller?

I have seen [Using applicationwillenterforeground for a passcode screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434469/using-applicationwillenterforeground-for-a-passcode-screen) but there has to be a better way or am I wrong? This will be for iOS 7 so if only 7 has such a functionality its ok but I am pretty sure it can be done on 6 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the app delegate handle the logic for the PIN view, and have that be a view, rather than a view controller. Just add the view as a subview of the window, and it will be shown over anything else.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    UINib *pinNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PINView" bundle:nil];
    UIView *pinView = [pinNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0];
    [self.window addSubview:pinView];
}
```

If you make the app delegate the File's Owner of the xib, then you can hook up any outlets you need in the view to the app delegate.

Comment: I see, but I do not have a nib file, the view is created programatically. What to do now?

Comment: @Majster, just create it programmatically in the app delegate.

Comment: I did get another idea, lets discuss this one first and if its bad ill do it programatically in the app delegate. How bout I set `self.viewController` as `UINavigationController` instead of my current one and init that navController with my current view controller. Will then pushing work? Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Majster you have already instantiated it in your example. Simply replicate that here.

Comment: @Majster, I'm not sure I do understand. If your controller hierarchy starts with a navigation controller, and all other controllers are pushed onto its stack, you could push the PinViewController. That would work no matter which controller was on screen. I don't know if it would work properly if you have some modal view controllers in there as well.

Answer (score 3):

If your root view controller is a NavigationController, then pushing or presenting should work in most cases. You already have all the code in place, just create a navigation controller. The only case this would not work is if there is a modal view controller already presented. In that case that needs to be dismissed first.

Here is a little messy implementation that takes care of this case too.

```
AKPresentedViewController *pres = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pres"];

UINavigationController *navi = ((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController);
if (navi.presentedViewController) {
    [navi.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [navi presentViewController:pres animated:NO completion:nil];
        }];
} else {
    [navi presentViewController:pres animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: @Majster I had the exact same idea. I saw your comment after I wrote this answer but thought it would still be acceptable.

Comment: Yes, appears I made a mistake somewhere, did create a navigation controller but pushing did not work. Doesn't matter anymore I have created the view in app delegate. It does look a bit messier but oh well... Thanks.

Comment: That's nice it worked for you. Upvoting doesn't hurt though if you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could present your PIN view controller the way they mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434469/using-applicationwillenterforeground-for-a-passcode-screen).

And for popping the PIN view controller I'm guessing that the user has to enter the correct PIN so the PIN view controller goes away. In that case it can pop itself:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Convert to [the objective-C codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18540832/1687981) to Swift 4, put the codes into **func applicationWillEnterForeground**

```
   let pres = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartVC")
    let navi: UINavigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    if ((navi.presentedViewController) != nil) {
        navi.dismiss(animated: true) {
            navi.present(pres!, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        navi.present(pres!, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```