# How do I force my ios7 app to start on the home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios7

I have an app with multiple View Controllers. I have a Home screen with "Play / Options / etc.".   When you hit Play, you navigate over to the GamePlay View Controller and start playing.

I find that if I'm in the "gameplay" VC and I hit the iPhone's Home button (leaving my app) and then re-launch my app, it puts me right back to the game screen.  I'd like to force the app to start on the same "Home" screen every time is it launched.

Suggestions greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

-Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the Home button, the application goes to background. When launched again, application just enters foreground from background. I think you can load the home screen in the following delegate method in AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

You can preserve the state of the game (I don't want to kill that zombie again!) in the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: Thanks Anindya.   With the keyword you gave, I did more research and found a good article: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539998/applicationwillenterforeground-present-a-view-controller.    Thanks again for the fast response!

Answer (score 2):

in your app's plist add the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` and set it to `YES`.
Your app wont be suspended and youll always start on the home screen

Comment: In recent XCodes you will find it as "Application does not run in background"

Comment: Daji: To be clear, addition the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to the pList means that in XCOde5, I add a line to the InfoPlist.strings... right?    Also, Anindya: I don't see "Application does not run in Background"... that would be simple :).